# Nodejs: how to troubleshoot a module on the Windows compatibility problems?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I'm using nodejs to write a command line tool. Windows reported error.No problem on Linux and Mac OSX systems.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/idoc

Global installation `npm install idoc -g`. Run `idoc init` command.You can reproduce this error.Dependencies [inquirer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer) error.

### Error message

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\npm\node_modules\idoc\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules\rx-lite\rx.lite.js:549
    throw e;
    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined
    at Interface.rl._getCursorPos (C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\npm\node_modules\idoc\node_modules\inquirer\                                               node_modules\readline2\index.js:55:51)
    at ScreenManager.render (C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\npm\node_modules\idoc\node_modules\inquirer\lib\ut                                               ils\screen-manager.js:19:27)
    at Prompt.render (C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\npm\node_modules\idoc\node_modules\inquirer\lib\prompts\i                                               nput.js:75:15)
    at Prompt._run (C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\npm\node_modules\idoc\node_modules\inquirer\lib\prompts\inp                                               ut.js:49:8)
    at Prompt.run (C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\npm\node_modules\idoc\node_modules\inquirer\lib\prompts\base                                               .js:57:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\npm\node_modules\idoc\node_modules\inquirer\lib\ui\p                                               rompt.js:83:12)
    at module.exports (C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\npm\node_modules\idoc\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules                                               \run-async\index.js:15:21)
    at C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\npm\node_modules\idoc\node_modules\inquirer\lib\utils\utils.js:16:7
    at tryCatcher (C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\npm\node_modules\idoc\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules\rx-                                               lite\rx.lite.js:537:29)
    at setDisposable (C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\npm\node_modules\idoc\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules\                                               rx-lite\rx.lite.js:5380:36)
```

Answer (score 1):

For easy debugging using chrome like browser debugger , you can use the [node-inspector](http://blog.nodeknockout.com/post/34843655876/debugging-with-node-inspector) package

Please follow the instructions in the above link to make it work.

Comment: My "IDOC" is a command line tool, you can use the "debugger"?

Comment: Sorry not for the command line, for command line i think the default debug module will work